# How to get year-date in sequence. It generates random in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the sql query I have wrote to populate year- month but it generates random. I want it to be like Jan -15, feb -15 ........dec-15, jan-16............dec-16....

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'January' then 'Dec ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2001)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'February' then 'Jan ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'March' then 'Feb ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'April' then 'Mar ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'May' then 'Apr ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'June' then 'May ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'July' then 'June ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'August' then 'July ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'September' then 'Aug ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'October' then 'Sep ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'November' then 'Oct ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'December' then 'Nov ' + convert(char(2),dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.YEAR-2000)
END
FROM
  dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR
```

So. If i query Month 
select distinct month from x_hist_vascular
This is the results i get 
month
February
June
August
April
May
December
January
September
October
July
November
March

If i do Asc or Desc it goes throw alpha order. Like for Asc it display April first and for Desc it displays September. I want months to be displayed in calendar format.

Comment: "Generates random"? What do you mean, there's nothing that would generate a random value in that query. What are you actually trying to do here. Sample data and expected results are going to be needed here I think,

Comment: Does `dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR` have a DateTime column with the date in?

Comment: It looks like it should work assuming the data is correct. What do yo mean it "generates random" - Show some sample data.

Comment: @Larnu and John Bustos I suspect it means the data is returned in an apparently random *order*. Gee351, would you confirm if that is the case, please?

Comment: Usually you "get things in sequence" with an `ORDER BY` clause.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: If i do this  select distinct month from x_hist_vascular                                     my results are : February
June
August
April
May
December
January
September
October
July
November
March                                                                        If i do order by it go throw the alpha order . if i do asc it starts with April , If i do desc it it starts with sept. I want the months in calender format

Comment: Do you have an actual date column you can order by instead of the string representation of the month name?

Comment: I recommend using an alias for `dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR` as well. Prefixing every column with that really bloats out the SQL. I'd probably use something like `XHV`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no columns with an appropriate data type to order by, which I suspect, you can add the following at the end of your query to sort by an numerical value for each month:

```
ORDER BY
CASE
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'January' then 12
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'February' then 1
...
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'November' then 10
WHEN dbo.X_HIST_VASCULAR.MONTH = 'December' then 11
END
```

Note, that the months are off by minus one in your query (`'January' then 'Dec '`, etc.). I did that here too, in the believe that this is intentional. If That was a mistake, you have to correct it in both places.

The best however would be, to revise the design and only use a column with a proper date/date time data type. That would make things a lot easier.

Comment: Yes that's intentional. For example : the data of April will be back filled into table with month named June. So June data for July.